# Programatically adding a Carousel as a SubView

Tags: ios, objective-c, carousel

I am trying to add Carousel on the View as follows. As I testing it, nothing happens, it does not even hit any of carousel delegate method.

**ViewController.h**

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) iCarousel *carousel;
```

**ViewController.m**

```
carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-50, self.view.frame.size.height-75)];
[self.view addSubview:carousel];

carousel.delegate = self;
carousel.dataSource = self;

self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;

self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    [carouselItems addObject:@(i)];
}
[carousel reloadData];
```

Comment: In which method are you running this code?

Comment: there is a method triggered by a button. In detail, I use `collectionView` and when user clicks on a `cell`, then I want my `carousel` appear. User clicks triggers a method where I add `carousel` as a `subView` of the `View`.

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to confirm your code is running?  What `frame` is it ending up with?  Is the carousel obscured by other views?

Answer (score -1):

Replace your code with this

```
self.carousel = [[iCarousel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(25, 50, self.view.frame.size.width-50, self.view.frame.size.height-75)];
self.carousel.delegate = self;
self.carousel.dataSource = self;
self.carousel.type = iCarouselTypeCoverFlow2;
[self.view addSubview:self.carousel];

self.items = [NSMutableArray array];
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
{
    [carouselItems addObject:@(i)];
}
[self.carousel reloadData];
```